# Strict stationarity implies bounded in probability

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

My definition of bounded in probabilty is following:

A random sequence $ \{ x_t : t \in \mathbb{Z} \}  $ is said to be bounded in probability, if 
$$ \lim_{c \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{t \in \mathbb{Z}} P( |x_t|>c) =0. $$
In a paper of A. Klivecka regarding the random GARCH it is said right after this definition:

Clearly, any strictly stationary sequence is bounded in probability.
Note that any sequence $\{ x_t : t \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ is bounded in probability if $\sup_{t \in \mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{E}|x_t|^p < \infty $ for some $p>0$ (by Chebychevs inequality).

Why are these staments true? Some more details would be really nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\{x_{t} \, \mid \, t \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is strictly stationary, then $\mathbb{P}\{|x_{t}| \geq c\} = \mathbb{P}\{|x_{1}| \geq c\}$ independently of $t$.  Moreover, by Chebyshev's inequality,
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{P}\{|x_{1}| \geq c\} \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}(|x_{1}|^{p})}{c^{p}}.
\end{equation*}
Therefore,
\begin{equation*}
\limsup_{c \to \infty} \sup\{ \mathbb{P}\{|x_{t}| \geq c\} \, \mid \, t \in \mathbb{Z}\} = \lim_{c \to \infty} \mathbb{P}\{|x_{1}| \geq c\} \leq \lim_{c \to \infty} \frac{\mathbb{E}(|x_{1}|^{p})}{c^{p}} = 0.
\end{equation*}